# Swap between images based on if statements in Flex 4.6

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

I'm working on a project and I have 5 images in a row. These images need to change (red, yellow, green) based on the outcome of an if, if else, else statement. 
I have some javascript that will do it but I need it in ActionScript3 for use with Flex 4.6.
JavaScript-- VV

```
if ((billableMonthHours/targetMTD) >= 1)
{
    MTDstatus.src = "green_led.png";
}
else if (((billableMonthHours/targetMTD) < 1) && ((billableMonthHours/targetMTD) >= 0.95))
{
    MTDstatus.src = "yellow_led.png";
}
else //if ((billableMonthHours/targetMTD) < 0.95)
{
    MTDstatus.src = "red_led.png";
}

if ((billableQuarterHours/targetQTD) >= 1)
{
    QTDstatus.src = "green_led.png";
}
else if (((billableQuarterHours/targetQTD) < 1) && ((billableQuarterHours/targetQTD) >= 0.95))
{
    QTDstatus.src = "yellow_led.png";
}
else //if ((billableQuarterHours/targetQTD) < 0.95)
{
    QTDstatus.src = "red_led.png";
}

if ((totalRecordedHours-mtdWorkingHours) >= 0)
{
    UTDcards.src = "green_led.png";
}
else if (((totalRecordedHours-mtdWorkingHours) >= -4) && ((totalRecordedHours-mtdWorkingHours) < 0))
{
    UTDcards.src = "yellow_led.png";
}
else //if ((totalRecordedHours-mtdWorkingHours) < -4)
{
    UTDcards.src = "red_led.png";
}
```

Thanks, I'm new to both JavaScript and Flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know how to load the images into Flash/Flex, [this would be a good place to start](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html). The `image` component is the usual way to put an image into a Flex application, and embedding will allow changes to happen faster, though with only a few images it shouldn't matter. Once it's embedded, you can set the `source` property:

```
[Embed(source="green_led.png")]
[Bindable]
public var greenLed:Class;
// ...etc

if ((billableMonthHours/targetMTD) >= 1)
{
MTDstatus.source = greenLed;
}
else if (billableMonthHours/targetMTD) >= 0.95)
// ...etc
```

Comment: this is my code:
`[Embed(source="green_led.png")]
[Bindable]
public var greenLed:Class

[Embed(source="red_led.png")]
[Bindable]
public var redLed:Class

[Embed(source="yellow_led.png")]
[Bindable]
public var yellowLed:Class

public function lightsChange: void
{
 var imgObj:BitmapAsset = new greenLed() as BitmapAsset;
 
 if (ratioGA <= 12.5)
 {
  GA.source = greenLed;
 }
 else if ((ratioGA > 12.5) && ratioGA <= 18.75))
 {
  GA.source = yellowLed;
 }
 else if (ratioGA > 18.75)
 {
  GA.source = redLed;
 }
}`

Comment: and my mxml for it:
`<s:SkinnableContainer id="lightButtons" fontSize="8">
<s:layout> <s:HorizontalLayout columnWidth="45" variableColumnWidth="false"/> </s:layout>
 <s:Image id="timeCards" width="20" height="20" 
   source="{GAlight}"/>

</s:SkinnableContainer>` 
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aside from the missing `()` in the definition of lightsChange, there's nothing I can say is definitely wrong there. You would have to provide more code and/or a better description of what is currently going wrong.

Comment: What do I put in the source spot in the mxml file?

Comment: Whatever you want to be the initial image. It's not a required field, though, so you could just leave it blank and let the `lightsChange` function set it.